# How can I use not equals in the get method and if statement

Tags: java

I am trying to loop through my customer list and see if the personal numbers match, otherwise it should throw an error that the customer doesn't exist. But I always get the error message that customer doesn't exist even when it does.

My method:

```
public ArrayList<String> getCustomer(String pNo){
   ArrayList<String> custInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(int i=0; i<customerList.size(); i++){
        if(customerList.get(i).getPersonalNumber().equals(pNo)){
        custInfo.add(customerList.get(i).getCustomerInfo());
        for(int j = 0; j<customerList.get(i).getAllAccounts().size(); j++){
            custInfo.add(customerList.get(i).getAllAccounts().get(j).getAccount());
        }
        return custInfo;
        }
       if (!customerList.get(i).getPersonalNumber().equals(pNo)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no such customer", "Error",       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    
}
return null;
```

}

When I write else after first if it does the same thing

Comment: The second conditional always runs if the first one fails. So, assuming the first item in your list doesn't match, you'll always get a failing condition.This would be better understood if you threw an exception instead of a GUI side effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if the personal number matches *on every iteration*. If the first customer does not match, you show the dialog, even if the second customer did match.

Since you have a `return` statement within the if-statement, the execution exits the loop when a matching customer is found. You can simply move `showMessageDialog` until after the loop, and it will run only when a matching customer is not found:

```
public ArrayList<String> getCustomer(String pNo) {
    ArrayList<String> custInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < customerList.size(); i++) {
        if (customerList.get(i).getPersonalNumber().equals(pNo)) {
            custInfo.add(customerList.get(i).getCustomerInfo());
            for (int j = 0; j < customerList.get(i).getAllAccounts().size(); j++) {
                custInfo.add(customerList.get(i).getAllAccounts().get(j).getAccount());
            }
            return custInfo;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no such customer", "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    return null;
}
```